# setMaxTotal and setDefaultMaxPerRoute in HttpClient?

Tags: java, spring, connection-pooling, apache-httpclient-4.x, resttemplate

I am using `RestTemplate` with `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory` as shown below:

```
private RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

// singleton class so only one instance
public DataProcess() {
    restTemplate.setRequestFactory(clientHttpRequestFactory());
}

private ClientHttpRequestFactory clientHttpRequestFactory() {
    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
    RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom().setConnectionRequestTimeout(1000).setConnectTimeout(1000)
            .setSocketTimeout(1000).setStaleConnectionCheckEnabled(false).build();
    PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager poolingHttpClientConnectionManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
    poolingHttpClientConnectionManager.setMaxTotal(300);
    poolingHttpClientConnectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(300);

    CloseableHttpClient httpClientBuilder = HttpClientBuilder.create()
            .setConnectionManager(poolingHttpClientConnectionManager).setMaxConnPerRoute(300).setMaxConnTotal(300)
            .setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig).build();

    requestFactory.setHttpClient(httpClientBuilder);
    return requestFactory;
}
```

**Now my question is:** What's the difference between setting `setMaxTotal` and `setDefaultMaxPerRoute` in `PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager` object versus setting `setMaxConnPerRoute` and `setMaxConnTotal` in `CloseableHttpClient`. Do I need to set these at both the places?

Also are there any other settings which we should use with RestTemplate? I am calling Restful service by using RestTemplate as my HttpClient so it has to be fast because this code will be running in a multithreading application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The builder parameters are used to construct a default pooling connection manager if you don't provide one. So in your example the sets on the builder are redundant.

See [HttpClientBuilder](https://github.com/apache/httpclient/blob/7d8ac569be11ffd52f6dcb03841319ffac1a77cd/httpclient/src/main/java/org/apache/http/impl/client/HttpClientBuilder.java) (sorry I had to snip this enormous method down a lot):

```
 public CloseableHttpClient build() {
    ... snip ...
    HttpClientConnectionManager connManagerCopy = this.connManager;
    if (connManagerCopy == null) {
        ... snip ...
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        final PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager poolingmgr = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager(
                RegistryBuilder.<ConnectionSocketFactory>create()
                    .register("http", PlainConnectionSocketFactory.getSocketFactory())
                    .register("https", sslSocketFactoryCopy)
                    .build(),
                null,
                null,
                null,
                connTimeToLive,
                connTimeToLiveTimeUnit != null ? connTimeToLiveTimeUnit : TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        ... snip ...
        if (maxConnTotal > 0) {
            poolingmgr.setMaxTotal(maxConnTotal);
        }
        if (maxConnPerRoute > 0) {
            poolingmgr.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(maxConnPerRoute);
        }
        connManagerCopy = poolingmgr;
    }
    ... snip ...
    return new InternalHttpClient(... snip ...);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. So that means I can safely remove those two properties from `CloseableHttpClient` right?

Comment: Also, do you think I should use any other property to get better  performance which I am missing here?

Comment: should do, if you have unit tests you could get the connection manager out and assert it's configured

Comment: looks good to me, stale checking is a good one to switch off but you have that. maybe make tcp nodelay configurable, but you are probably well into premature optimization if you don't have any measurements.

Comment: Yeah I am measuring it as well one by one by enabling/disabling the settings. I was trying to use tcp nodelay but I was not able to understand how to do that in my current code? My intention is get idea what other people think will be best for optimizations and keep measuring it until I am satisfied.

Comment: Looking at their docs it's enabled by default 'This parameter expects a value of type java.lang.Boolean. If this parameter is not set, TCP_NODELAY will be enabled (no delay).'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80975/discussion-between-david-and-roby).